# How to find xpath of a dropdown value using cucumber capybara

Tags: selenium, xpath, cucumber, capybara

How do i find the xpath of an option in the dropdown 'sort by' in 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=nav_cs_gb'

I have tried using
find(:xpath, ".//*[@id='sort']/option[starts-with(text(), 'Price: Low to High')]").select_option

But its not working. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the page in your browser you'll see that the select box you're looking at isn't actually visible on the page.  It is hidden and replaced with a JS created dropdown widget.  Something along the lines of

```
find("span[data-gbfilter-dropdown='{\"attribute\":\"sortOrder\"}'] span.a-dropdown-prompt").click
click_link('Price - Low to High')
```

should do what you're trying to do